# How to get total internal memory (including system memory)

Tags: android, storage, environment

This code return total internal memory size:

```
public static String getTotalInternalMemorySize() {
    File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
    long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
    return formatSize(totalBlocks * blockSize);
}
```

But this size is without system used memory.

For example, at the GALAXY NOTE 3 is the **total internal memory of 32 GB**, but this function **returns only 26.18 GB**.

**How to determine the overall internal memory including missing 5.82 GB of system memory?**

Comment: Why would anyone be interested about memory that they can not use?

Comment: Because I want to know the total capacity of the internal memory, as indicated by the manufacturer.

Comment: I don't see how could this be useful, but I guess you could obtain it by looking for the first number which is greater than the amount and is a power of 2.

Comment: What number do you have in mind?

Comment: 32 = 2^5. First bigger than 26.18.

Comment: It occurred to me somehow ... :D

Please write this response as a solution (the question will be answered and you will be added some points)  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea that may work is to compute the first number which is power of two, and it is bigger than the number you got returned from the function.

```
Ex: 2^5 = 32 > 26
```

In this case your number is 32. You should convert to integer before comparing obviously.